# How to pass data from TableViewCell class of a View Controller to another ViewController via segue Swift 4?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, swift4

I have `ViewController1` and `ViewController2`.`ViewController1` have a `TableView` with a `TableViewCell` class to update its UI.

What I want to do is,when user click on a `button` inside the `TableViewCell` in `TableView` of `ViewController1`, then will segue to `ViewController2` and pass a data along.

***Here is what I tried:***

**In TableViewCell class**

```
protocol MyDelegate : class {
    func showSecondVc(postId : Int)
}

class MyTableCell : UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate : RefreshDelegate?

    @IBAction func myButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.showSecondVc(postId: posts.postId)
    }
}
```

**In ViewController1 :**

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate , MyDelegate {

  func showSecondVc(postId: Int) {
      print("button tapped : \(postId)")
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSecondVc", sender: self)
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "showSecondVc" {
        //here I want to pass the **postId** to ViewController2
    }
  }

}
```

Until this point I can get `postId` in `ViewController1` when a button is click in any `tableCell` .

Now the problem is the `postId` is inside `showSecondVc()`,how can I pass the `postId` to `ViewController2` when I perform segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a var in ViewController2 and call it postID

```
func showSecondVc(postId: Int) { 
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSecondVc", sender: postId)
}
```

and set it in prepare

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "showSecondVc",
     let secondVC = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
     secondVC.postID = sender as! Int
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store `postId` so that you can have it in `prepare(for:sender:)`, and then just try to get `ViewController2` from `segue.destination`:

```
private var postId: Int = 0

func showSecondVc(postId: Int) {
    print("button tapped : \(postId)")
    self.postId = postId
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSecondVc", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSecondVc",
        let secondVC = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
        secondVC.postId = self.postId
    }
}
```

Comment: @ken can you please tell me why you liked Sh_Khan's answer better than mine?

Comment: cause his answer included the `postId` into the sender..I personally think is better..Just my personal opinion

Comment: @ken fair enough

Comment: @ken sure, no problem :)